# Spring integration passing multiple argument between methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration in order to do some http request and then parse it an finally save it into database
I want to have access to  `App` object in convert method, as you can see `App` object is argument of the `download` method(that is called from another channel) , What is the solution?
Here is my code :

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "channel1", outputChannel = "channel2")
public ResponseEntity<DetailsItemParser[]> download(App app)
{
    String url = config.getAppDetailUrl();
    try
    {
        SSLUtil.turnOffSslChecking();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application","json")));
    HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
    detailsCrawlerRestTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    ResponseEntity<DetailsItemParser[]> responseEntity = detailsCrawlerRestTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, DetailsItemParser[].class, app.getExternalId());

    return responseEntity;

}

@Splitter(inputChannel = "channel2", outputChannel = "channel3")
public List<DetailsItemParser> scrape(ResponseEntity<DetailsItemParser[]> payload)
{
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(payload.getBody()));
}



@Filter(inputChannel = "channel3", outputChannel = "channel4")
public boolean filter(DetailsItemParser detailsItemParser)
{
    final Set<ConstraintViolation<DetailsItemParser>> violations = validator.validate(detailsItemParser);
    if (violations != null && !violations.isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Transformer(inputChannel = "channel4", outputChannel = "channel5")
public App convert(DetailsItemParser payload)
{

    App app = appRepository.findById(payload.getId());

    LOG.info("entry={}", o.toString());
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple arguments are possible if you have exact match for the `payload`, everything rest must be configured via `@Header`. You can't have two `payload`, as well as you can't have two returns from Java method.

So, if you would like to carry `App` object alongside with the `ResponseEntity<DetailsItemParser[]>` consider to add it into the `headers`.

You can use `HeaderEnricher` before sending to the `channel1` or return a whole `Message<?>` from the `download()` method and add `App` to header using `MessageBuilder`.

The `convert()` method then can be specified as:

```
public App convert(DetailsItemParser payload, @Header("app") App app)
```

**UPDATE**

The `HeaderEnricher` sample via Java Config:

```
    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "routingSlipHeaderChannel", outputChannel = "processChannel")
    public HeaderEnricher headerEnricher() {
        return new HeaderEnricher(Collections.singletonMap(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.ROUTING_SLIP,
                new RoutingSlipHeaderValueMessageProcessor(routeStrategy())));
    }
```

More info in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#_configuring_a_header_enricher_with_java_configuration

Comment: Thanks.How can i use HeaderEnricher with spring boot and java?

Comment: Can you please post an example java code with using HeaderEnricher?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.